# extract number only after specific word by skipping other word in between it

Tags: r, regex

I'm looking for a two-digit number that comes before the word "years" and a seven- or eight-digit number that comes after the word "years." An example of the data is shown below.

`data <- "mr john is 45 years old his number is 12345678, mr doe is 57 years 7654321"`

`data <- as.list(data)`

I tried this approach and was successful in getting two digit numbers before the word "years" :

`stringr::str_extract_all(data,regex(".\\d{2}\\s(?:year)"))`

I also tried this method to get the number after word "years" :

`str_extract_all(data,regex(".\\d{2}\\s(?:year).\\d{7,8}"))`

I managed to get the number that appear directly after the word years :

`" 57 year 7654321"`

However, I was unsuccessful in getting eight digit numbers following the word "years" that included other characters in between the number and the word "years".

How can I retrieve the number only after the word "years" by skipping this other word/character?

I really appreciate your help

Comment: Can you confirm the expected output? Note your input has got no `57 year 7654321` substring

Comment: Thank you, the expected outcome would be 
```45 years 12345678, 57 years 7654321```

Comment: Akrun's solution will work for you if your strings cannot contain another digit between the `year` and the 7-8 digit number.

Comment: `years old his number is` is the middle of the digits ? Otherwise digits, not digits, digits is your solution and there is none other

Comment: What if the string were "john is 45 his number is 12345678, mr doe 7654321"? Both `"12345678"` and `"7654321"` come after `"years"`.  I suspect you only want the former but that is not clear from how you have stated your question. Your question needs clarification. Remember, examples are provided for illustration; they are not a substitute for a complete and unambiguous statement of the question in words.

Comment: Perhaps you want to match `(?<!\d)(\d{2}) +years\b.*?(?<!\d)(\d{7,8})(?!\d)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FigD6P/1). For each match capture group 1 holds the 2-digit number and capture group 2 holds the 7 or 8 digit number. Note that, for example, `\d{7,8}` matches `"1234567890123456789"`; hence the need for the negative lookbehind and lookahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `str_replace` to match and remove the non-digits before and after the 'years' and then extract the digits before and after the years including the 'years'

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str_replace_all(data,
     "(?<=years)\\D+|(\\D+)(?=years)", " "), "\\d{2}\\s+years\\s+\\d{7,8}")[[1]]
[1] "45 years 12345678" "57 years 7654321"
```

---

Or another option is to capture the digits, along with the 'years' substring with `str_match` and then `paste` them together

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
str_match_all(data, "(\\d{2})\\D+(years)\\D+(\\d{7,8})")[[1]][,-1] %>% 
     as.data.frame %>% 
     invoke(str_c, sep =" ", .)
[1] "45 years 12345678" "57 years 7654321"
```

#### data

```
data <- "mr john is 45 years old his number is 12345678, mr doe is 57 years 7654321"
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this fix my problem

Comment: What if the string were "john is 45 years old 1 his number is 12345678"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland in that case, may be `str_match_all(data,  "(\\d{2})\\D+(years).*(\\d{7,8})")[[1]][-1]#
[1] "45"      "years"   "2345678"`.  You are right that it I made the pattern based on the assumption that there are no digits in between

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R approach:

1. Create a list with `strsplit` separating by `,`
2. define a function `my_func` that takes a string and searches for  numeric before year and after year and then pastes all together.
3. Use `lapply` to apply your function to the list.
4. Use `toString()` to get the expected output.

```
my_list <- strsplit(data, ",")

my_func <- function(x){
a <- as.integer(sub(".*?(\\d+)\\s*year.*", "\\1", x))
b <- as.integer(sub(".*?year.*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", x))
paste(a, "year", b)
}

result <- lapply(my_list, my_func)
lapply(result, toString)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "45 year 12345678, 57 year 7654321"
```